# Styling multiple same-level elements on hover

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

I have HTML markup like this:

```
<div id="blocks">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to style all the `.block` elements that aren't hovered when I hover on a `.block`.  Is there a way that this can be accomplished with just CSS?

Can I do this with a CSS rule similar to `.block:hover .block:not(:hover)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#blocks:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.block:hover { 
    background-color: yellow;   
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CeF9t/).

**Alternative solution**

```
.block:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

#blocks:hover .block:not(:hover) { 
    background-color: yellow;   
}
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CeF9t/1/).

Answer (score 2):

`#blocks:hover .block {}` for all non hovered elements, but a hovering over the whole `#blocks` element and `#blocks .block:hover {}` for the hovered element should work.